# Julia Pluto cannot find dev installed package

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook, pluto.jl

I have my own Julia package called `foo` which is stored in `/private/tmp/foo` and looks like:

```
foo
├── Project.toml
└── src
    └── foo.jl
```

I'd like to use it in an experiment I'm going to run. As such I

1. Create a new dir called `bar` for my experiments
2. Create a new Julia env to use `Julia`, `]`,`activate .`
3. I now install `foo` with `(bar) pkg> dev /private/tmp/foo`

I can now use `foo` within `bar`

```
julia> import foo
[ Info: Precompiling foo [79e59c38-1f99-4492-a045-e17729c6f495]

julia> foo.greet()
Hello World!
```

I now install Pluto with `(bar) pkg> add Pluto`, and open a new Pluto notebook. Even though I’m still in the `bar` env, which has `foo` installed I get a `ArgumentError: Package foo not found in current path:` as shown in the image below.

[image: Pluto cannot find foo]

How can I create my own module, install and use it within a notebook? Ideally with `Revise.jl` still working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even though I’m still in the bar env,

Have you checked that you are still in it? Did you manually activate the environment?

In recent versions, Pluto notebooks have their own individual environments that are stored inside the notebook file. You can either:

- `dev` your package inside this notebook environment too, or
- explicitly activate the outside environment [like the Pluto wiki describes](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl/wiki/%F0%9F%8E%81-Package-management#pattern-the-shared-environment). For eg:

```
begin
    import Pkg
    # activate the shared project environment
    Pkg.activate(Base.current_project())
    # instantiate, i.e. make sure that all packages are downloaded
    Pkg.instantiate()

    import foo
end
```

Comment: Interesting, coming from my experience of Jupiter notebook I expected the Pluto notebook ran in the same env which launched it from. It seems I should read up on how Pluto manages packages

Using `Pkg.develop(path="/private/tmp/foo")` in the notebook works

Comment: The lack of managing its own environment is one of the reasons why results in Jupyter notebooks are often difficult to reproduce. The Pluto package manager solves this issue. It would be great if Pluto also supports dev packages or non-default package versions with its own package manager, but this is on the long-term agenda.